# How to use generic DbContext in a monolithic architecture?

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, dbcontext

I'm starting with the base architecture of a monolithic project, I'm trying to implement a generic DbContext within a layered architecture, specifically within the Common project, which will be the reference in all the other layers.

My problem is given by the use of AspNet Identity, where the DbContext must Inherit from IdentityDbContext and pass an argument of type ApplicationUser or TUser.

The issue is that my ApplicationUser class is inside the Domain project, which contains all the classes that represent my database model.

I don't want my Common project to have the reference of some other project, because it assumes that this would be a generic project for general use.

How is the best way to solve this architecture?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SgJer.png)

I try to have a BaseUserEntity base class inside the Common project and have this be my TUser that needs IdentityDbContext, but it gets complicated when I have to generate the configuration of the database tables...

I have a model where I will implement several types of users.

UserA
UserB

And that all these inherit from my ApplicationUser, due to the inconvenience that I have, it could not move forward with the development.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you're looking to actually move away from the monolyth and want to switch to a generic, rapid, development system. Then you can try and use [Vidyano](https://vidyano.com). The documentation has remained basic, but I've put [together a guide](https://medium.com/@pieterjandeclippel/rapid-development-using-vidyano-fb185605b060) on how to get started with it. Instead of typed DTO classes, it uses a generic `PersistentObject` approach with attributes. You can then optionally create an `XxxActions` class to modify how this type is stored in the database

Comment: For the basic/intermediate stuff I can assist you with this. The frontend is developed using WebComponents and open-source. The backend is sadly not open-source... We always use ravenDB as database system, because it's easier for a generic approach

Comment: Also, to enable you to move away from a monolithic database, we're using a ravendb feature known as replication. This replicates objects from a source database to your other database at all time, so even at database level your small applications are seperated. The creation of objects from the target applications into the source database used to happen through code in the `Service/XxxWeb.cs`/an api-token generated in your source application/a webrequest from the target app to the source app. It's been simplified recently, but I'd still have to investigate that...